# GitHub actions not passing environment variables to Vite build

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to create a GitHub action to deploy a React Application on a S3 Bucket. The issues that I am having are related to the **environment variables** being backed during build with Vite.

When all the checks on the GitHub action pass and the app is deployed, seems like none of the ENVS have been passed in.

```
name: Upload to S3

on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        env:
          VITE_APP_BASE_URL: ${{ secrets.VITE_APP_BASE_URL }}
          AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_REBRAND_BUCKET_NAME }}
          VITE_APP_ALGOLIA_APP_ID:  ${{ secrets.VITE_APP_ALGOLIA_APP_ID }}
          VITE_APP_ENVIRONMENT: development
      
      - name: Yarn Install
        run: yarn install
      - name: Yarn Build
        run: yarn build
      - name: Deploy app build to S3 bucket
        run: aws s3 sync ./build/ s3://${{ secrets.AWS_REBRAND_BUCKET_NAME }} --delete
```

my `yarn build` command is just `"build": "vite build"`. Something strange I have noticed is that the configure secrtes such as `aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}` are passed correctly.

I'm not sure why the rest of my **envs** are not passed at all. Is my yaml not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have placed the environment variables under the `Configure AWS Credentials` step. You should move these variables to the `Yarn Build` step, as that is where they are needed. Another option is to move them to the job level to make them accessible at each step.

Answer (score -1):

[Disclaimer - This answer relevant only if you're trying to access that variable in the client (browser).]

Vite inject env variables to the build output only if it's prefixed with "VITE_"

see -
https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode#env-files

> To prevent accidentally leaking env variables to the client, only variables prefixed with VITE_ are exposed to your Vite-processed code. e.g. for the following env variables:
>
> ```
>    VITE_SOME_KEY=123
>    DB_PASSWORD=foobar
> ```
>
> Only VITE_SOME_KEY will be exposed as import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY to your client source code, but DB_PASSWORD will not.